# Prove that a Linear-Map is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I want to show that the following linear map is surjective :

let $V = \{p ∈ ℝ[X];~\deg p ≤ 2\}$
$$
g=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
   V \rightarrow \Bbb R^3  \\
   g(p(x))= (p(0);p(1);p(-1))
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

With $a(x) = ax^2+bx+c$

**Here is what I did:**

Let $a',b',c'\in\Bbb R^3$

We have to find $g(p(x)) = (a';b';c')$

$a'=p(0), b'=p(1),c'=p(-1)$
i.e      $a'=c, b'=a+b+c, c'= a-b+c$

Is that a rigorous proof of the linear map's surjectivity?

Comment: What is $R2[X]$? Did you mean to write $ℝ[X]$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to write it but it's all the polynoms with a degree inferior or equal to 2

Comment: Write “Let $V = \{p ∈ ℝ[X];~\deg p ≤ 2\}$” in the beginning and change $g$’s signature to “$V → ℝ^3$”. (You mean “less or equal to”, by the way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If $(a’, b’, c’) ∈ ℝ^3$, you indeed have to find a polynomial $p ∈ V$ such that $p(0) = a’$, $p(1) = b’$ and $p(-1) = c’$, but you cannot define such a polynomial $p$ by simply “setting its values” at $0$, $1$ and $-1$. It is unclear how that defines a polynomial. (And defining it is really the very thing you are asked to do in this exercise!)

If I ask you what polynomial you got that does the job, you need to show it to me. And I don’t want to see “The polynomial $p$ with $p(0) = a’$, $p(1) = b’$ and $p(-1) = c’$.” – that doesn’t tell me anything. I expect something like “The polynomial $p = X^2 + 2X - 3$” or maybe “The polynomial $p = X^2 + (b’-c’)X + a’$” (both of which would be bad choices as none of them does the job).

*Hint*, regarding the exercise. You already showed that $g$ is linear? Then it suffices to find such polynomials $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ in $V$ which are mapped via $g$ to

- $(a’,b’,c’) = (1,0,0)$,
- $(a’,b’,c’) = (0,1,0)$, and
- $(a’,b’,c’) = (0,0,1)$.

(Why is that? How can you can find a polynomial $p ∈ V$ for general $(a’,b’,c’) ∈ ℝ^3$ if you have $p_1, p_2$ and $p_3$?) To construct for example $p_1$: Notice that you need to have $p_1(1) = 0$ and $p_1(-1) = 0$. Can you construct a polynomial of degree $2$ which has exactly these two zeroes? How can you modify it so that $p_1(0) = 1$? Proceed similarly for $p_2$ and $p_3$.